# Разное расположение вспомогательных файлов при отладке. Почему?

Tags: c++, отладка

При отладке приложения в v.studio создаются 2 папки, одна для временных файлов, в другую помещается скомпилированный экзешник. Если я делаю приложение, использующее dll, то для запуска отладки в vs и обычного запуска приложения через проводник dll должна быть помещена в папку, где лежит скомпилированный экзешник. Если же я делаю приложение, открывающее файл, то при отладке txt должен находится в папке с исходниками программы. Иначе не открывыет его. При запуске приложения из проводника, txt уже должен быть в папке с екзешником. Пример:

```
void f1 () {
    string name;
    cin >> name;
    ifstream ist (name.c_str());
    if (!ist) {
        cout << "\n" <<"error" << "\n";
    }
}
```

1. Почему при работе с dll и открытии файла txt необходимо их разное месторасположение при отладке?
2. Можно ли сделать настройку, что бы txt при отладке мог находится в папке с exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. При открытии обычного файла средствами стандартной библиотеки без указания пути файл будет открываться *в текущей рабочей директории*. Для поиска же динамических библиотек (DLL и т.п.) используется совершенно другой системно-зависимый алгоритм.

   Динамические библиотеки - это критически важные файлы особой природы. Не ничего удивительного в том, что для их поиска применяется особый алгоритм.
2. Запускайте ваш exe так, чтобы в этот момент рабочей директорией являлась именно папка exe.

   Или самостоятельно в вашей программе определяйте, где располагается ваш exe и явно указывайте этот путь при открытии txt файла.

Все это на самом деле не имеет никакого отношения к отладке.

Comment: Похоже на "вы должны сделать правильно, тогда будет правильно работать." Так а как это сделать? )

Comment: @pucher: Сделать что именно? В пункте 2 моего ответа сразу же указан вариант, при котором все будет работать сразу, в текущем виде. Вас это не устраивает? Если нет, то будем разбираться дальше.

Comment: Не понимаю, как сделать то, что написано в п.2.

Comment: @pucher: В Windows? Например, создать shortcut для вашей программы. В настройках shortcut есть поле для указания начальной рабочей директории. Укажите в качестве рабочей директории именно директорию, содержащую ваш exe (оно и по умолчанию должно так быть). Все.

Comment: "оно и по умолчанию должно так быть". Да, если txt положить в папку с приложением, то при запуске приложения в win (не через vs), оно видит txt в своей папке и открывает его. Теперь проблема. При компиляции приложения в vs создается папка debug, куда помещается exe. Если поместить в debug txt, то при запуске в vs отладки запускается exe из папки debug. Который не видит txt, лежащий в папке с отлаживаемым exe.

Comment: @pucher: В настройках вашего VS проекта (раздел "Debugging"/"Отладка") есть отдельная строчка для указания "Working Directory". Обычно так указано `$(ProjectDir)`. Вместо этого укажите там `$(TargetDir)`.

Comment: Да, заработало.